# gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, mfslidemenu

I know the meaning of unrecognized selector issue. It is always due to calling a method which is not implemented or not found. I have the selector implemented and I can see it as well.

Still I am getting this error. I am using [MFSlideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu) control.

It works great for me until user signout and sign in again. After sign in, when user click on navigation bar item, my app crashes saying:

```
[__NSCFType gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc882da0
```

I am setting root controller in my `AppDelegate` like this:

```
    LeftMenuViewController *leftSideMenuController = [[LeftMenuViewController alloc] init];
    RightMenuViewController *rightSideMenuController = [[RightMenuViewController alloc] init];
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                    containerWithCenterViewController:self.meNavigationController
                                                    leftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuController
                                                    rightMenuViewController:rightSideMenuController];
    [[self.meNavigationController.viewControllers lastObject] viewDidLoad];
    self.window.rootViewController = container;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Then, in my `viewController`, I am setting `navBarItems` according to this control in my `viewDidLoad` method.

Here I am setting `navBarItems`:

```
#pragma mark - UIBarButtonItems

- (void)setupMenuBarButtonItems {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self rightMenuBarButtonItem];
    if(self.menuContainerViewController.menuState == MFSideMenuStateClosed &&
       ![[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:self]) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self backBarButtonItem];
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self leftMenuBarButtonItem];
    }
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)leftMenuBarButtonItem {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
            initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"reveal-icon.png" ofType:nil]] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
            target:self
            action:@selector(leftSideMenuButtonPressed:)];
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)rightMenuBarButtonItem {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
            initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"reveal-icon.png" ofType:nil]] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
            target:self
            action:@selector(rightSideMenuButtonPressed:)];
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItem {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:BACK_BUTTON_NAVIGATION_BAR_BUTTON_STRING style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
}

#pragma mark - UIBarButtonItem Callbacks

- (void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)leftSideMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:^{
        [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
    }];
}

- (void)rightSideMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleRightSideMenuCompletion:^{
        [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
    }];
}
```